# Can I get str_extract to take a piece of text in the middle of a file name?

Tags: r, stringr

A different program I am using (Raven Pro) results in hundreds of .txt files that include nine variables with headers. I also need the file name that each line is being pulled from.

I am using `stringr::str_extract(names` in order to get a file name thrown into a dataframe with rbindlist. My problem is that I only want a portion of the file name included.

Here's an example of one of my file names -

```
BIOL10_20201206_180000.wav.Table01.txt
```

so if I do `("\\d+"))` to try and get numbers it only picks up the 10 before the underscore, but the portion of the file name I need is `20201206_180000`

Any help to get around this is appreciated :)

```
library(plyr)
myfiles <-  list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.txt", full.names = FALSE)
dat_tab <- sapply(myfiles, read.table, header= TRUE, sep = "\t", simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
names(dat_tab) <- stringr::str_extract(names(dat_tab), ("\\d+"))   
binded1 = rbindlist(dat_tab, idcol = "files", fill = TRUE)
```

ended up with file name coming in as "10" from the file name "BIOL10_20201206_180000.wav.Table01.txt"

Comment: FYI, `library(plyr)` is not being used here.

Answer (score 1):

A couple other options:

```r
x <- "BIOL10_20201206_180000.wav.Table01.txt"

#option 1
sub("^.*?(\\d+_\\d+).*$", "\\1", x)
#> [1] "20201206_180000"

#option 2
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=_)\\d+_\\d+")
#> [1] "20201206_180000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the length:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "\\d{8}_\\d{6}")
# "20201206_180000"
```